# Building binary tree from bottom up

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

Consider the following program, which builds a binary tree from top to bottom by splitting nodes to halves:

```
def split(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    m = n//2
    return [split(n-m)] + [split(m)]
```

For example:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(i, split(i))
```

prints:

```
1 1
2 [1, 1]
3 [[1, 1], 1]
4 [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
5 [[[1, 1], 1], [1, 1]]
6 [[[1, 1], 1], [[1, 1], 1]]
7 [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], 1]]
8 [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]
9 [[[[1, 1], 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]
```

Is it possible to build the exact same tree from bottom up? That is, given number of `1`'s, recursively merge two adjacent nodes until there is nothing more to merge?

If not, is it possible to build similar tree from bottom up, with exact same height?

To illustrate the process, take for example 6:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
[1, 1], 1, 1, 1, 1
[1, 1], 1, [1, 1], 1
[[1, 1], 1], [1, 1], 1
[[1, 1], 1], [[1, 1], 1]
[[[1, 1], 1], [[1, 1], 1]]
```

How do I know when to "skip" a node so that it is merged later?

PS: The example is in Python but the language does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let n be the initial size of the array 
for(int i=0;i<log2(n);i++)
{
    Let the current size of the array be m
    for(int j=0;j<m/2;j++)
        merge two adjacent elements of the array to form a new element
    // After this some elements from first half would be single

    for(int j=m/2;j<m;j++)
        merge two adjacent elements of the array to form a new element.  
    // After this some elements from second half would be single

    // The new updated array will now have ceil(n/2) elements
}
```

Comment: That's top to bottom. See "merge two **adjacent** nodes".

Comment: However for n = 12, it will build tree of the form [[[[1,1],[1,1]],[1,1]]],[[[1,1],[1,1]],[1,1]]]] and not [[[[1,1],1],[[1,1],1]],[[[1,1],1],[[1,1],1]]]